# Symlink error when installing MySQL via Homebrew

Tags: macos, permissions, mysql, homebrew

Trying to install MySQL via Homebrew. The install seems to work fine but i get an error:

```
"Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link mysql'"
```

Naturally, after this I ran:

```
brew link mysql
```

Which spat out:

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/include/typelib.h
/usr/local/include is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

So I ran it with `sudo` and got a "cowardly refusing to brew link mysql".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Obviously that folder doesn't belong to you. Just try with:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include
```

You **never** have to use `brew` with `sudo`. If you do, something is wrong with your installation.

Then, try the `link` command again.

Comment: When I do I'm getting this error .. chown: /usr/local/include: No such file or directory ..

Comment: There is no directory named like include. I get errors with another directory, so I run it for /usr/local  and works fine.

Answer (score 9):

slhck's answer is great, but I think it is a little cleaner if you are a member of the admin group (probably are if you are using Homebrew) to make all locations in /usr/local writable to group.

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

Comment: did not work for me when linking nmap installed by brew on a mac. chosen answer worked.