# symlink file error

Tags: macos, permissions, mysql, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symlink error when installing MySQL via Homebrew](https://superuser.com/questions/435442/symlink-error-when-installing-mysql-via-homebrew)

[Similar to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/435442/symlink-error-when-installing-mysql-via-homebrew) but have problems still trying to solve the issue.

I am trying to install mySQL and it keeps telling me it's not writable and that I should change its permission.

Now I did try all the answers but I still end up with the same error. Here are the codes I tried:

- `sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/lib`
- `sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local`
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include`
- `sudo chmod -R g+w /usr` (desperate enough)

As for OS system I use I am using OSX Lion.

Comment: Since you say it's the same question, but the existing answers don't help you, then instead of posting the same question again please consider commenting and/or [adding a Bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) to the existing question to garner more/different answers

Comment: @techie007 I don't think the OP has enough rep to do either of your suggestions.

Comment: The problem is probably that your user does not belong to the group that owns `/usr/local/lib`. Add your user to that group and try the commands again.

Comment: How do I do that terdon? sorry, I am still new with a mac.

Comment: terdon you are right I got it I am able to link.

Comment: @techie007, I wasn't disagreeing, I just wanted to point out that he could not do so hoping that you might have another suggestion that he _could_ try since you've got a good deal more experience with SE than I :). In any case, I think its resolved now, voting to close.

Comment: @terdon I fully realize what you're saying and why it can be confusing.  I'm not trying to argue anything, or bag on anyone, just spreading the info on how things are supposed to work around here. :)